# Simple calendar grid for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Most of the lovely calendar components I've found are too complex for my simple requirement.  I need to show a month grid, with indications of whether individual days are booked or not.  I don't need to handle several events per day, etc.  I could adapt one of these to always expand a booking into a full day event I suppose.

What can readers recommend for this?  My goal is to show which days are booked for a bed and breakfast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen lots of great calendars out there.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'too complex' since you didn't go into much details of the issues you were having but some of my favs are:

FullCalendar - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
jMonthCalendar - http://code.google.com/p/jmonthcalendar/
jQuery Events Calendar - http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/

I know you probably need a month view calendar but this week calendar is great for scheduling:
Week Calendar - https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/demos

Comment: Agreed. FullCalendar is a great plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using glDatePicker - http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/

There are only 3 stylesheets provided but you can make more to better suit your website.

My only real problem with it is that while you can make a limited range of dates selectable (via the selectableDates and selectableDateRange JSON properties) I can't find easy ways to do the inverse. If, like me, the data you have is the days that are booked you'll have to do some work to calculate the appropriate selectableDateRange and selectableDates to represent the dates that aren't booked for this datePicker to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add [Kalendae](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae) though I've never used it.  Source was [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/2012/03/12/nools-procstreams-kalendae/).  It looks nice and compact.  Might not meet your needs completely, but just throwing it onto the pile.